# Unit Test code coverage problem on Controller Class Solved thanks every one

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]

> Here is the Controller where i facing problem

public class RerenderEx {

```
public contact con{set;get;}
public boolean Abool{set;get;}
public boolean Bbool{set;get;}    

public RerenderEx()
{
    con=new contact();
    Abool=false;
    Bbool=false;
}
public void saveNew() {
    insert con;
    con.clear();//con=new contact();
}

public void saveSec() {
    insert con;
    Abool=true;
}

public void EditSec() {
    Abool=false;
    Bbool=true;
}

 public void updateSec() {
    update con;
}
```

}

> Here is the Test Class.This is unable cover Functions if one covered other not covered plz help me to resolve the issue

@isTest

public class RerenderEx_TC

{

```
static testMethod void testMthd()
{
 boolean Abool=false;
 boolean Bbool=false;    
RerenderEx r=new RerenderEx();
 contact con=new contact(lastname='xxx');
r.saveNew();
 insert con;
 con.lastname='xyy';
 update con;
  r.saveSec();
 r.EditSec();
 r.updateSec();
 }
```

}

Comment: You provided your code, but you haven't asked a question.  Be sure to clearly state where you need help.

Comment: test classes don't test VF pages - they test VF controllers by, in effect, simulating the data values passed from the page to the controller (to setters), verifying action methods, and verifying the results of getters and action methods

Comment: Sorry,by mistake i posted VF page..actually i know test classes test Controllers not Pages...Thanks for your replay..@crop

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was never a real question to begin with, and then OP answered with code that should have been in the original question. Closing because it won't be of use to anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When testing a visualforce page controller/extension you need to have the code load the page, take a look at the sample test found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm):

```
@isTest

public class thecontrollerTests {

    public static testMethod void testMyController() {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.success;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        thecontroller controller = new thecontroller();
        String nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

        // Verify that page fails without parameters
        System.assertEquals('/apex/failure?error=noParam', nextPage);

        // Add parameters to page URL
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('qp', 'yyyy');

        // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
        controller = new thecontroller(); 
        controller.setLastName('lastname');
        controller.setFirstName('firstname');
        controller.setCompany('acme');
        controller.setEmail('firstlast@acme.com');
        nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

        // Verify that the success page displays
        System.assertEquals('/apex/success', nextPage);
        Lead[] leads = [select id, email from lead where Company = 'acme'];
        System.assertEquals('firstlast@acme.com', leads[0].email);
    }
}
```

Notice the Test.setCurrentPage which is basically programmatically loading the visualforce page.

Answer (score 0):

> This is similar to above Issue which resolved.I posted for reference.
>
> Controller Class

public class RerenderEx1
{

```
public Boolean Abool{set;get;}
public Boolean Bbool{set;get;}

public RerenderEx1()
{
    Abool=false;
    Bbool=false;
} 
public void CallB() {
    Bbool=true;
   Abool=false;
}

public void CallA() {
    Abool=true;
    Bbool=false;
}
```

}

> here it is the Test Class for above Controller with 100% Code coverage.

@isTest

public class RerenderEx1_TC

{

```
static testMethod void testMthd()
{
    RerenderEx1 re1=new RerenderEx1();
    
    boolean Abool=false;
    boolean Bbool=false;
    
    re1.CallB();
    re1.CallA();
}
```

}